# if im using lazy loading module my angular application main.bundle.js file size is decreased while build

Tags: angular, angular5, lazy-loading, ng-build

How can i reduce my `vendor.bundle.js` and `main.bundle.js` file size while build my application using

> ng build --aot false --prod

if im using lazy loading module my angular application `main.bundle.js` file size is decreased while build.

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng build by itself does not have any optimizations. If you ng build --help you can see all the flags you can pass to further optimize your code and reduce the output sizes.

Try ng build -prod -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimizer and see what your numbers are. This will enable production mode, use AOT, use a vendor chunk for third party libs, pull all common code out into a common chunk, make sure the output path is clean and lastly use the @angular-devkit/build-optimizer for further optimizations.

If that is still large, then do a run through in your application for third-party libraries that you are using. (1) Are you importing the entire RxJS library? (2) Moment with all localizations? etc..